# VBA error 1004 when assigning array with a formula to range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

When trying to dump my array to a range I get an error 1004, but only when there is a formula in the array containing brackets.

```
Dim DataArray(27, 11) as Variant
Dim wod as Worksheet
dim rng as Range
Dim d as Range
Dim ArrayEnd as Integer
```

This is my array

```
For y = 0 To lastrowo
                    If Not IsEmpty(d.Offset(y, 0).Value) Then
                        DataArray(y, 0) = d.Offset(y, 0).Value2
                        DataArray(y, 1) = d.Offset(y, 10).Value2
                        DataArray(y, 2) = d.Offset(y, 14).Value2
                        DataArray(y, 3) = d.Offset(y, 16).Value2
                        DataArray(y, 4) = d.Offset(y, 19).Value2
                        DataArray(y, 5) = d.Offset(y, 22).Value2
                        DataArray(y, 6) = d.Offset(y, 25).Value2
                        DataArray(y, 7) = "=ROUND(F" & y + 3 & "-G" & y + 3 & ";0)"
                        DataArray(y, 8) = "=G" & y + 3
                        DataArray(y, 9) = d.Offset(y, 28).Value2
                        DataArray(y, 10) = d.Offset(y, 31).Value2
                        DataArray(y, 11) = d.Offset(y, 36).Value2
```

This is the offending part, if I remove brackets and ";" it all works.

```
DataArray(y, 7) = "=ROUND(F" & y + 3 & "-G" & y + 3 & ";0)"
```

And this is where I get the error

```
Set rng = wod.Range("A3:L" & ArrayEnd + 3)
                        rng = DataArray
```

I even tried replacing the formula with this variant

```
"=ROUND" & Chr(40) & "F" & y + 3 & "-G" & y + 3 & Chr(59) & "0" & Chr(41)
```

and this is how it looks in my array

[image: Watch]

Comment: Did you try a `,` instead of `;`?

Comment: Yeah that's what did it, localization strikes again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use US English format in formulas sent from VBA to Excel - so try replacing the ; with a ,